# File Dependency failures where in fact file exists

Tags: azure-application-insights

Application insights shows a dependency failure stating a file was not found. However the file exists on the server and the application works fine.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1g6N.png]

[image]

API version: 2.1.0

Hopefully some one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you have something making a web-like request to a file on disk?

that might work for *you* from the local machine but if *someone else* hits the site from any other machine, then "d" doesn't mean anything *to them*.  I don't have a D drive and even if it did my D drive doesn't have your png in that place.

someone else's web browser loaded your page, and tried to load an image from `D:\home\site\wwwroot\....`

somewhere in HTML you have something like:

```
<img src="D:\home\site\wwwroot...\image.png"/>
```

but you should have something like

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

or

```
<img src="data/pdfletter/image.png"/>
```

or something with a *relative* path within the website, not an *absolute* path on the machine hosting the site.

in this case, it looks like Application Insights is working correctly and telling you that someone else can't load your images?

Comment: Thank you for the effort.  But the files are not used in HTML or client side but to generate a PDF on server side in .net. The file works correct on the server, so this is not the problem.

Comment: The AI dependency collector saw an event go by (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener.oneventwritten(v=vs.110).aspx) and that event said something tried to make a request to read that file, the status indicated that file read failed.

if you're seeing this a lot you might want to either disable the dependency collector, or filtering these out using the custom filtering/sampling functionalities in the sdk, or possibly submit a bug against https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server where this code is.

Comment: (it is possible that the dependency collector is interpreting the statuscode of undefined as a failure in this case?)